# Round a TimeSpan value to first integer

Tags: c#, date, timespan

[image]I want to find the total number of days between two DateTime values. So I have created totaldays which performs the subtraction:

```
TimeSpan totaldays = enddatedata - startdatedata;
```

I want to round the TimeSpan to the first whole number e.g 13 instead of 13:00:00:00 as I want to add the value 13 into the database. For testing purposes I am using a label to display the result:

```
lbltotaldays.Text = (totaldays.ToString());
```

How can I round the value to only the first number?

```
    protected void insertbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int? recurrencedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRecurrence.Text);
        if (recurrencedata == 1)
        {
            int moduledata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlModule.Text);
            DateTime startdatedata = Convert.ToDateTime(txtstartdate.Text);
            DateTime enddatedata = Convert.ToDateTime(txtenddate.Text);
            int classtypedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlClassType.Text);
            int roomcodedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRoomCode.Text);
            int starttimedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlStartClassTime.Text);
            int endtimedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlEndClassTime.Text);

            startdatedata = DateTime.Parse(txtstartdate.Text).Date;
            enddatedata = DateTime.Parse(txtenddate.Text).Date;
            TimeSpan totaldays = enddatedata - startdatedata;

            string DefaultConnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(DefaultConnection);

            myConnection.Open();

            string query = "INSERT INTO Class (ModuleId, ClassTypeId,  ClassScheduleStartTimeId, ClassScheduleEndTimeId, RoomCodeId, StartTime, EndTime, RecurrenceId, TotalDayNumber) VALUES ( @moduledata, @classtypedata, @starttimedata, @endtimedata, @roomcodedata, @startdatedata, @enddatedata,  @recurrencedata, @totaldaynumberdata)";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moduledata", moduledata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classtypedata", classtypedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdatedata", startdatedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddatedata", enddatedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttimedata", starttimedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomcodedata", roomcodedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtimedata", endtimedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recurrencedata", recurrencedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totaldaynumberdata", totaldays);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();

            SuccessPanel.Visible = true;
            lbltotaldays.Text = (totaldays.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TimeSpan.TotalDays is a double value with the timespan in whole and fractional days.  You can round this to an integer using Math.Round.

Comment: Thanks would you be able to provide an example in context with my code? Many thanks

Comment: The problem that you are seeing has nothing to do with what you are passing: the field that has a problem is of DB type `time`, and it gets overflown, because you are setting a time span of 14 days into it; DB time can take a time span of at most 23:59:59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get the number of full days from `TimeSpan`, use its `Days` property:

```
lbltotaldays.Text = totaldays.Days.ToString();
```

This will disregard the number of hours, so, for example, 13 days 22 hours and 5 minutes will produce `13`.

If you would like to treat 13½ days as 14, call `Math.Round` on the [`TotalDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
lbltotaldays.Text = ((int)Math.Round(totaldays.TotalDays, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure this works when displaying it in the label but the label was just to test what value it would display. I want to actually insert the the value e.g 13 into the database column 'TotalDayNumber' which set to an int

Comment: @DavidCraven Skip the `ToString` then - i.e. go with `(int)Math.Round(totaldays.TotalDays)` or `(int)totaldays.Days`, depending on whether you need rounding or not.

Comment: Note that the default for Math.Round is to use banker's rounding, so 12.5 is rounded to 12. I think you forgot to specify the rounding method, like `Math.Round(totaldays.TotalDays, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`. Or `Math.Ceiling` might be appropriate.